# Unable to import PyroModule

Tags: python, pyro

I am trying to import PyroModule using: `from pyro.nn import PyroModule` but, I am getting this error:

ImportError: cannot import name 'PyroModule' from 'pyro.nn' (/home/karima/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyro/nn/**init**.py)

Here is the whole piece of code:

```
import os
from functools import partial
import torch
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pyro
import pyro.distributions as dist
from torch import nn
import seaborn as sns
from pyro.nn import PyroModule
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with my MAC. None of the suggestions worked for me. I resolved it by running `python -m pip install pyro-ppl`
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is due to wrong installation of pyro module,

instead of this

```
pip install pyronn
```

can you try this

```
pip install pyro-ppl
```

Let me know how this goes

Comment: Hi Dhinesh.. Thanks for your answer .. I tried to install pyro using `pip install pyro-ppl` but, the installation interrupts after a while telling that the process is killed!

Comment: Can you create a virtual environment and then install the package!?

Comment: I think this problem is fixed now .. I uninstalled pyTorch and reinstalled it .. then I installed pyro .. however, I am getting now another error: `Import error: cannot import name 'shared intermediates' from 'opt_einsum' (unknown location)`!

Comment: By the way, I am using a virtual machine (OS: ubuntu)

Comment: Virtual environment is different from virtual machine

Comment: Yes, I got your point Dhinesh .. my code is running on a virtual environment that I've created using conda.

Comment: This seems to be issue with your virtual environment, you can check this https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34351 for more info

Comment: Not yet! I am still getting this message:

Comment: Import error: cannot import name 'shared intermediates' from 'opt_einsum' (unknown location)!